Rolling linear regression slope over n rows by group
My data are at the ID-month level with a payment at every month. It is sorted by id and dt. What I'd like to do is a create a new column that, for each group, holds the linear slope for the next N months of payments. Here is a sample:
data = {"id": ['a','a','a','a','a','a'], "dt": ['2024-01-01', '2024-02-01', '2024-03-01', '2024-04-01', '2024-05-01', '2024-06-01',], "pmt": [3341,3205,3287,3544,6536,5994]}
df = pl.DataFrame(data, schema={"id": pl.String, "dt": pl.Date, 'pmt':pl.Int64}).with_columns(pl.col("dt").set_sorted())
print(df)

Which looks like the following:
shape: (6, 3)
┌─────┬────────────┬──────┐
│ id  ┆ dt         ┆ pmt  │
│ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---  │
│ str ┆ date       ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪════════════╪══════╡
│ a   ┆ 2024-01-01 ┆ 3341 │
│ a   ┆ 2024-02-01 ┆ 3205 │
│ a   ┆ 2024-03-01 ┆ 3287 │
│ a   ┆ 2024-04-01 ┆ 3544 │
│ a   ┆ 2024-05-01 ┆ 6536 │
│ a   ┆ 2024-06-01 ┆ 5994 │
└─────┴────────────┴──────┘

I know that the linear regression slope for this ID for this block of 6 months is 671.86, so that value would go on the first row. The next row would have the slope for the next rolling 6 months, etc. So result would look like (obviously rows 2-6 have fake slope data; just for visual):
shape: (6, 4)
┌─────┬────────────┬──────┬───────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ dt         ┆ pmt  ┆ slope_pmt_next6mo │
│ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---  ┆ ---               │
│ str ┆ date       ┆ i64  ┆ f32               │
╞═════╪════════════╪══════╪═══════════════════╡
│ a   ┆ 2024-01-01 ┆ 3341 ┆ 671.859985        │
│ a   ┆ 2024-02-01 ┆ 3205 ┆ 700.25            │
│ a   ┆ 2024-03-01 ┆ 3287 ┆ 646.210022        │
│ a   ┆ 2024-04-01 ┆ 3544 ┆ 683.880005        │
│ a   ┆ 2024-05-01 ┆ 6536 ┆ 547.179993        │
│ a   ┆ 2024-06-01 ┆ 5994 ┆ 525.48999         │
└─────┴────────────┴──────┴───────────────────┘

I assume I'd use some flavor of polars.DataFrame.rolling but I don't quite follow the syntax. I tried the following but the result creates NaN on the first two rows so not sure what's going on:
def ols_slope(y: pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:
    # Calculate linear regression slope
    x = y.rank("ordinal")
    numerator = ((x - x.mean())*(y - y.mean())).sum()
    denominator = ((x - x.mean())**2).sum()
    return numerator / denominator

(
    df
    .rolling(index_column=("dt"), period="6mo", closed='none', check_sorted=False)
    .agg(ols_slope(pl.col("pmt")).alias("pmt_slope"))
)


I'm a little confused by your usage of x = y.rank("ordinal") so I'm doing something else.
If we assume dt always starts on the first of the month and you want the time variable to be number of months you can do
def ols_slope(x: str| pl.Expr, y: str|pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:
    # Convert string input to pl.col
    if isinstance(x,str):
        x=pl.col(x)
    if isinstance(y,str):
        y=pl.col(y)
    # Convert date to integer
    x = pl.arg_where(x==pl.date_range(x.min(), x.max(), '1mo'))+1
    # Calculate linear regression slope
    numerator = ((x - x.mean())*(y - y.mean())).sum()
    denominator = ((x - x.mean())**2).sum()
    return numerator / denominator

For the next part where you're getting NaN at the front instead of the end, that's because rolling takes -period as the default for offset but you want -1mo so altogether you'd do
(
    df
    .rolling('dt', period='6mo',group_by='id',offset='-1mo')
    .agg(slope=ols_slope('dt','pmt'))
)

Incidentally, check out the polars_ds plugin for more tools around data science including regressions.
For example, with it, you could do
# Get a numeric value for month
month_number = (
    pl.arg_where(
        pl.col('dt')==pl.date_range(pl.col('dt').min(), pl.col('dt').max(), '1mo')
        )+1
)
(
    df
    .rolling('dt', period='6mo',group_by='id',offset='-1mo')
    .agg(
        slope=pds.query_lstsq_report(
            month_number , 
            target='pmt', 
            add_bias=True
            ).first().struct.field('coeff')
        )
    )


Thanks, Dean. Couple questions regarding the polars_ds syntax which appears to be more straightforward. What is the pl.arg_where... statement accomplishing? What does the first() accomplish?

the arg_where line converts the dt into an integer month by creating a series of all the months from min to max and then finding which argument (index) of that series the current value is. The first is b/c query_lstsq_report returns the results in rows where the intercept is the first one.

I'm getting the following error:
TypeError: rolling() got an unexpected keyword argument 'group_by'
Any idea?

what version are you on? do a help(df.rolling) and look for the parameter that says something like "Also group by this column/these columns"

It looks like I have a newer version and can use df.groupby_rolling. This looks like it almost works: result = df.groupby_rolling(index_column='dt', period = "6mo", offset = "-1mo", by='id', check_sorted=False).agg(slope_pmt_next_6mo = ols_slope(pl.col("pmt"))) but the slope in my first row is 713 when I'm expecting 671 according to Excel.
